# Apache ActiveMQ's main instance does not start in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, openjdk

I have installed the `activemq package in Ubuntu {12.04|14.04|14.10}

In the LTS releases the service works fine, but in the 14.10 dist release the `activemq` does not work:

```
# ln -s /etc/activemq/instances-available/main /etc/activemq/instances-enabled

# /etc/init.d/activemq console main

Starting with Console ActiveMQ instance  main
INFO: Loading '/etc/activemq/instances-enabled/main/options'
INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
INFO: Starting in foreground, this is just for debugging purposes (stop process by pressing CTRL+C)
mkdir: missing operand
Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_75 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
  Heap sizes: current=506816k  free=498429k  max=506816k
    JVM args: -Xms512M -Xmx512M -Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/activemq/tmp -Dactivemq.classpath=/etc/activemq/instances-enabled/main; -Dactivemq.home=/usr/share/activemq -Dactivemq.base=/var/lib/activemq/main -Dactivemq.conf=/etc/activemq/instances-enabled/main -Dactivemq.data=/var/lib/activemq/data
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /usr/share/activemq
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /var/lib/activemq/main
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /etc/activemq/instances-enabled/main
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /var/lib/activemq/data
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
 INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@1a85a3b0: startup date [Thu Jan 29 11:27:52 BRST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
***Failed to execute main task. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor***
   ...done.
```

Can anyone help me?